# Sliding Window Flink

Tags: bigdata, apache-flink

Of particular interest to us are sliding window queries. Given a
finite epoch τ = (t0,t1,...,tn) of n timepoints, a sliding window
query is a triple SWQ = f,l,p. where f stands for the frequency
of the query, l stands for the length of the sliding window, and p
specifies the required event pattern we would like to identify. For
the sake of clarity and without loss of generality, we assume that n
is a multiple of f (n mod f = 0). Can Someone please write a code related to it in flink. Please I am trying to apply parameters of flink where

```
f: number of events generated inside flink
l: number of events generated in volume (size)
p: Pattern -> number of variety generated in events
```

Comment: It's not clear what the units of frequency and length are -- are these measured in time, or by counting events? But to get started, have a look at HOP windows in Flink SQL https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-tvf/#hop or sliding windows in the Window API https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sir. Actually this is measured in n timestamp epoch. It is used for counting events in term of generation time and reception time.I have looked into this sliding windows in Windows API.

Comment: For the stack overflow community to be able to help, we'll need to see a concrete example with sample inputs and expected outputs, and preferably also some code that illustrates what you have in mind, and an indication of where you are stuck.

Comment: Well, I am working on research paper based on Probabilistic management for late arrival of events. It's about applying sliding window query  approach to handle the late arrival inside the streaming data. They are using three parameters which are mentioned above. I am stuck in including these three parameters in my model to handle the late arrival of events. I am looking for help. I am share you link of the paper. Please look at the page number 2 (MODEL AND PROBLEM STATEMENT).

Comment: You will be able to understand my requirement. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325883292_Probabilistic_Management_of_Late_Arrival_of_Events

Comment: The implementation described in that paper (see section 3.2 and figure 5) is appropriate. You don't want to use Flink's built-in windowing for this. I suggest you contact the authors and ask if they have code they can share.

Comment: I am trying to contact the authors. But Still not able to connect. Actually Sir, everything is based on parameters when I am able to understand parameters which are mentioned above using algorithms will be easy to do. Can you please figure out. How can I use these parameters in the flink built-in windowing approach.